# How do I put the textarea tag inside a div tag?

Tags: html, tags

I want to put a textarea on my webpage, but it has to be inside a div tag in order to keep my layout. I don't want the users to be able to re-size the textarea until it's out of the div tag I put it in, it messes up the hole layout. Is there a way to set the max size on the textarea?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (although it is a little sloppy) is to style the textarea in-line. If you define a width and resize:none, your users will not be able to resize the textarea and ruin your design.

```
<div>
  <textarea name="yourtextarea" style="width:300px;height:200px;resize:none;" /></textarea>
</div>
```

I would however recommend that you style your textarea similarly to how Xander has answered as it is much cleaner.  I would change one thing though, and that is to add a less generic selector.

```
<head> // place in your header
  <style type="text/css">
    #textAreaId {
      width:300px;
      height:200px;
      resize:none;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body> // place inside of your div, within the body tag

  <div>
    <textarea id="textAreaId" name="yourtextarea" /></textarea>
  </div>

<body>
```

Comment: interesting how you took my `height` declaration when the OP didn't specify he needed a height and took it a step further by adding it inline in the html ... why not just vote me up ?!

Comment: @Xander Bro, I answered at almost exactly the same time.  I, like you, took it another step further and figured that he was probably looking for a fixed size, not just width. I did not see your answer before posting, and I believe we can both agree that these answers are not ground-breaking...

Comment: @Victorkilo Hey that "resize:none;" CSS is just what i needed to stop the users from dragging the textarea! Thanks man.

Comment: @Xander And the only reason I haven't removed my answer is because it directly shows him how to place a text area in a div.

Comment: @VictorKilo it is not correct. where's the closing `div` tag?

Comment: @Xander I was actually just adding that when you commented. And for the record, I have +1d your answer.

Answer (score 5):

**CSS:**

```
textarea {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    resize:none; /* disable resize functionality */
}
```

Comment: That helps a lot. Really appreciate it Xander